# Java Graphics doesn't display anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

so I'm trying to do a project in Eclipse and my Eclipse doesn't show anything. 
I mean, the code is fine but it just opens an window and it shows nothing in it, when it should show a line.

FirstGraph.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FirstGraph extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setName("First Graph");
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        f.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(50, 50, 250, 280);
    }
}
```

MyCanvas.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyCanvas extends JComponent{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2508263540396372610L;

    public void Paint(Graphics g){
        int[] x;
        x = new int[]{40, 125, 256, 290};
        int[] y;
        y = new int[]{50, 115, 279, 295};

        g.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
    }
}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Change `public void Paint(Graphics g){` to `@Override public void Paint(Graphics g){` ..

Comment: instead of `paint` use `paintComponent` method, use `@Override` annotation.

Comment: `f.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);` better to get `MyCanvas` to return a sensible preferred size and `pack()` the frame.  Also, don't try to override any painting in the frame..

Comment: In addition to wise advices, `FirstGraph` class extends from `JFrame` but you add the canvas to another local `JFrame` in *main* method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is case-sensitive.
I wrote `public void Paint(Graphics g){..}`, instead of `public void paint(Graphics g){..}`, So my problem has been resolved.

Comment: *"Apparently, it is case-sensitive."*  Sure is.  But as mentioned, override `paintComponent(Graphics)`, and only in the `JComponent`.